# crop an image getting error

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, crop

I am trying to implement a cropping pod to my Xcode project.

I am getting this error and i am not sure why.

can anyone help.

```
   let imageRef = imageToCrop!.cgImage!.cropping(to: visibleRect)
    let result = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!, scale: imageToCrop!.scale,
        orientation: imageToCrop!.imageOrientation)

    return result
}
```

but getting this error

> Ambiguous use of 'init(CGImage:scale:orientation:)'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [`init(cgImage:scale:orientation:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624091-init) not `init(CGImage:scale:orientation:)`.

```
let result = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!, scale: imageToCrop!.scale, orientation: imageToCrop!.imageOrientation)
```

Comment: You should vote to close this question as a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced.